# Ubuntu 12.04.2 with intel i845 graphics becomes sluggish after few minutes of system startup

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, intel

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS installed from LiveCD. It works fine when system boots but after sometime it hangs for few seconds (about 2 to 4 seconds) showing a garbage screen and then becomes sluggish.

It happens every time I boot my system. I think that it is because of my graphics card driver. I have intel i845G 64 MB of graphics card. I have tried updating my xserver-xorg-video-intel graphics driver, but sometimes it becomes more sluggish at time of boot itself.

I am searching for this solution for a very long time but was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TenPlus1, I really appreciate for your reply :D

Actually before trying your suggestions, I experimented something new and it is looking good till now.
Here is my story:

1. After updating my repository I noticed that some new packages were listing in Synaptic Package Manager(might be because of Ubuntu 12.04.3 release).
2. Then I installed Linux Kernel 3.8.0 by selecting packages:

   ```
   linux-generic-lts-raring
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
   linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

and restarted my system. It successfully installed Linux Kernel 3.8

1. Then I installed all -lts-raring packages for Xserver-Xorg using command prompt:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring libxatracker1-lts-raring xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring libxrandr-ltsq2 x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring xserver-common-lts-raring
   ```

it removed already installed Xserver-Xorg packages which was meant for -lts-quantal

1. Then restarted my system again..
2. and then.. It works great.. :-)

Till now I have not realized any type of problems, running my system for more than 2 hours.
I think that it was because of Older Linux Kernel and Older Xorg drivers..
I also noticed that it slightly inhanced my system performance. :)
Now I'm able to play games on Wine also(I was not able to play previously), videos are playable as well.

If I will get any type of problem, I will certain use your suggestion.

Thanks again.. :D

Answer (score 1):

To use the available fix, run the following commands:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/855gm-fix
apt-add-repository ppa:brian-rogers/graphics-fixes
apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
aptitude update
aptitude install linux 855gm-fix-dkms
aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Why do you need to do a dist-upgrade?